# iphone xcode; mutableCopy still immutable?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

i have looked all over the place regarding this problem. All i am trying to do is, create a nsuser defaults object, then add a mutable array to it and try to modify the nsuserdefaults object.

```
//Created a sample array
NSMutableArray *xml=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[xml addObject:@"x"];
[xml addObject:@"x"];
[xml addObject:@"x"];
[xml addObject:@"x"];
[xml addObject:@"x"];
//assigned to defaults object which is created previously with a mutableCopy
[defaults  setObject:[xml mutableCopy] forKey:@"userLocationsDetailedXML"]; 
//Tried to modify the defaults object - which at this point should be mutable
[[defaults objectForKey:@"userLocationsDetailedXML" ] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"y"] ;
```

Adding `[defaults synchronize]` does'nt help either.

But surprisingly the defaults object is still immutable. It is __NSCFArray, not __NSCFArrayM as expected
Any suggestions?

edit: console output
Class : __NSCFArray => SHould'nt it be _*NSCFArrayM since i created a mutable copy?
[*_NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the array as NSMutableArray, using

```
[(NSMutableArray *)[defaults objectForKey:@"userLocationsDetailedXML"] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"y"] ;
```

that should take care of it.

EDIT:

Given that you can't actually store NSMutableArrays in `NSUserDefaults`, I recommend that you just go ahead and reassign the entire thing, like so:

```
NSMutableArray *xml = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [xml addObject:@"x"];
    [xml addObject:@"x"];
    [xml addObject:@"x"];
    [xml addObject:@"x"];
    [xml addObject:@"x"];

[defaults  setObject:xml forKey:@"userLocationsDetailedXML"]; 
[xml release];
```

Then, for changing the values,

```
NSMutableArray *userLoc = [[defaults objectForKey:@"userLocationsDetailedXML"] mutableCopy];
[userLoc replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"y"];
[defaults  setObject:userLoc forKey:@"userLocationsDetailedXML"]; 
[userLoc release]; //thanks, dreamlax!
```

Comment: HI sam, that did'nt help either - it still throws an error that the array is immutable. But woul'dnt [xml mutableCopy] create a mutable array? why is it immutable in this case?

Comment: Ooh, good stuff on that other answer! Looks like you can't use NSUserDefaults to take care of this particular problem.

Comment: Just edited my answer with a suggestion for how to do this better.

Comment: @Sam: Good workaround but don't forget to relinquish ownership of `userLoc` when you're done, otherwise you'll have a leak :)

Comment: Hi there, yeah i thought of doing the same thing, recreating the whole array - but the problem here is, there could be multiple places where this is done, for example, am creating copies of a view, where each copy fetches data and writes to defaults, in this case, i am afraid that there might be a time when 2 views are writing to defaults at the same time and if that happens, the results could be ugly. Thanks for the tip on the leak, in my actual code am releasing xml.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve using stringForKey: will be immutable.

Also, you have a rather ugly leak; you are the owner of the object returned by `mutableCopy` but you have no way to relinquish ownership because you have lost the only reference to that object (the `xml` array is mutable anyway).

Comment: hmm, interesting, that would mean a lot of logic change for my app :(
I missed that in the docs, thanks for the info - i would have been cracking my head to find a solution where there is no solution :)